# C# service does not write to Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp;

Tags: c#, dll, service, windows-7, .net-4.5

I am using a third party DLL that logs its execution to `Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\3rdPartyDLL.log;`

When I call this DLL from a C# Console Application the log is created and written.

However, when I call this DLL from C# Service, log is not created. The DLL works fine though.

What can be the reason that C# Service behaves differently? Do I need to give it some additional rights? Service is using `LocalSystem Account`.

Comment: Which folder did you check for this data then? Be aware that the appdata folder for "LocalSystem" is not under the "c:\users" folder, it is under "C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData" (change according to your drive and installation differences).

Comment: I've checked all folders just in case. I haven't had folder specified by you, I've added it manually but still no effect. Log file does not appear.

Comment: use [EventSource logging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/08/13/windows-high-speed-logging-etw-in-c-net-using-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource/) and not to log files, this is so old school. now run a listener (own tool with real time listener or capture it to an ETL file and read it with Perfview / WPA.exe) to get the events

Comment: Da hell you are talking about? Have you read my question at all? I am using external DLL, I have no impact how logging is performed. And BTW there is **nothing wrong** with logging to a file.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar, and in my case the file was locked by another procces, u can use debugger for ur service or also use try catch and in catch block log the ex

Comment: Thanks, but file can't be locked because it has to be created at the first place by the DLL.

Comment: wrap line with IO in try catch any way, and log in catch. U would narrow direction of problem

Comment: Mate, there is nothing to wrap around. The DLL does not return any errors.

Comment: @NikitaSahan So you're saying that to figure out where the log file is located he should log its location?